# how to fill UITableViewCell TextLabels with NSDictionary value?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary

I am on the last stage of setting up my Indexed Uitableview for fast scrolling, Once I have finished this I am going to write about my experience to hopefully help anyone that is trying to achieve the same results as myself.
However I have one last step passing my NSDictionary values into my tableviewcells textlabels.. I'm just not sure how to do it and hoping someone can provide me with an example.

This is what my dictionary looks like

```
Dictionary: {
    H =     (
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda,
        Honda
    );
    M =     (
        Mazda,
        Mazda,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi,
        Mitsubishi
    );
    N =     (
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan,
        Nissan
    );
    T =     (
        Toyota,
        Toyota,
        Toyota
    );
```

I have tried a few random things but am pretty much clueless about passing a NSDictionary  to the uitableview... heres what i Have attempted inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
//..
[[cell textLabel] setText:[[arraysByLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
//..
```

arraysByLetter is my NSDictionary

and the line of code is giving me this warning
 **'NSMutableDictionary' may not respond to 'objectAtIndex:'**

any help would be greatly appreciated

**UPDATE:::**

I have found a great example of how to populate the uitableview cell textlabel with a NSString that is created like so

```
NSString *value = [arraysByLetter objectForKey:[[arraysByLetter allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = value;
```

arraysByLetter being my sorted NSDictionary, however this is causing a program received **signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"** not sure why but trying to work through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confusing an `NSMutableDictionary` with an `NSMutableArray`. The former accesses objects by `key`s, typically `NSString`s, and the latter by `NSUIntegers`.

For example, if `dict` is an `NSMutableDictionary`, then you might call

```
[dict objectForKey:@"myKey"];
```

If `array` is an `NSMutableDictionary`, then you might call

```
[array objectAtIndex:0];
```

For the example you give, you have an `NSDictionary` where the `objectForKey:` is an `NSArray`. Therefore you should be calling something like

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"H"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

to output `"Honda"` or

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"M"] objectAtIndex:2];
```

to output `"Mitsubishi"`.

Comment: okay I get that.. I also have an array of first letters.. so I think I could make some type of loop checking which objectforkey it is then doing a objectAtIndex array count or something.. I think.. going to try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an array method call on a dictionary.  In a dictionary, you get its members by using a key that is associated with that object (member).  In an array, you get a member of the array by using the index into the array.

You are using an index where a key is needed.